# How to convert a signed Long in Kotlin to a ByteArray while preserving sort order?

Tags: kotlin, io, byte

I am trying to convert a regular (signed) `Long` to a `ByteArray` in Kotlin, such that the lexicographic order of the resulting `ByteArray`s is the same as the order of the input `Long` values.

Consider this test case:

```
class LongToByteArrayTest {

   @Test
   fun canConvertLongToByteArrayPreservingOrder(){
        // some long values to test with
        val longs = mutableListOf(
            Long.MIN_VALUE, 
            Long.MAX_VALUE, 
            0, -1, +1, -2, +2, -10, +10, -42, +42, 
            Long.MAX_VALUE / 2, Long.MIN_VALUE / 2
        )
        longs.sort()

        for ((lower, upper) in longs.windowed(size = 2)) {
            println("Lower: ${lower}, Upper: ${upper}")
            assert(lower < upper) { "Fail: long values are out of order!" }

            val lowerBytes = toStableBytes(lower)
            val upperBytes = toStableBytes(upper)

            assert(compareBytesLex(lowerBytes, upperBytes) < 0){ "Fail: byte arrays are out of order!" }
        }
   }


   fun compareBytesLex(byteArray1: ByteArray, byteArray2: ByteArray): Int {
        val min = min(byteArray1.size, byteArray2.size)

        for (i in 0 until min) {
            val myByteUnsigned = byteArray1[i].toInt() and 0xff
            val otherByteUnsigned = byteArray2[i].toInt() and 0xff
            val cmp = myByteUnsigned - otherByteUnsigned
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp
            }
        }

        return byteArray1.size - byteArray2.size
   }

   fun toStableBytes(value: Long) : ByteArray {
       TODO("how do we do this?")
   }

}
```

Essentially, I'm looking for a method body for `toStableBytes` which makes the test pass. Ideally, the byte array for a single long should be exactly 8 bytes in length.

I tried `ByteBuffer#putLong(...)`, `DataOutputStream#writeLong(...)` and some other solutions provided by the JDK, but unfortunately none of them provides order-preserving byte arrays. I also tried manual little-endian-encoding, but this also doesn't have the desired property.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that numbers are in 2's complement, so negative numbers are "bigger" than non-negative numbers if you just look at the bytes. For example, -1 is `11111111` while 1 is `00000001`. On the other hand, the binary representation of positive numbers grows naturally (`0001`, `0010`, `0011`, etc), while for negatives it's the other way around: -3 is `11111101`, -2 is `11111110`, -1 is `11111111`. So there's no simple "stable" ordering for both bytes and numbers – unless you use 8 bytes and implement an algorithm that converts the minimum in your range (`Long.MIN_VALUE`) to `000...0` and the maximum in your range (`Long.MAX_VALUE`) to `111...111`.

Something like this should work

```
fun toStableBytes(value: Long): ByteArray {
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE_BYTES)
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    byteBuffer.putLong(value)
    val msb = byteBuffer.get(7) // get the most significant byte
    byteBuffer.position(7) // go back 1 position in the buffer to overwrite it later

    // now flip the most significant bit
    if (value < 0) {
        byteBuffer.put(msb.and(0x7F))
    } else {
        byteBuffer.put(msb.or(-0x80))
    }

    // reverse the array to put the most significant byte first (big endian)
    return byteBuffer.array().reversedArray()
}
```

Comment: Yep, that algorithm is exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: ah got it! Let me update my answer then

Comment: @MartinHäusler I update my answer. I just realised you found the response somewhere else and it's basically using the same approach, but with a different implementation

Comment: On second thought you don’t need to make it little endian and then reverse it - you can do everything in big endian in the first place. It would be a bit faster that way

Answer (score 0):

Ok, courtesy of [Exodus LongBinding](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/blob/0a0fd05209606f7d4e443e5cd168797c7ebe9743/openAPI/src/main/java/jetbrains/exodus/bindings/LongBinding.java#L38) I've found a solution which seems to work:

```kotlin
    fun writeLong(out: OutputStream, long: Long) {
        writeUnsignedLong(out, long xor Long.MIN_VALUE)
    }

    private fun writeUnsignedLong(out: OutputStream, long: Long) {
        out.write((long ushr 56).toByte().toInt())
        out.write((long ushr 48).toByte().toInt())
        out.write((long ushr 40).toByte().toInt())
        out.write((long ushr 32).toByte().toInt())
        out.write((long ushr 24).toByte().toInt())
        out.write((long ushr 16).toByte().toInt())
        out.write((long ushr 8).toByte().toInt())
        out.write(long.toByte().toInt())
    }

    fun readLong(stream: InputStream): Long {
        return readUnsignedLong(stream) xor Long.MIN_VALUE
    }

    private fun readUnsignedLong(stream: InputStream): Long {
        val c1 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c2 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c3 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c4 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c5 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c6 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c7 = stream.read().toLong()
        val c8 = stream.read().toLong()
        if ((c1 or c2 or c3 or c4 or c5 or c6 or c7 or c8) < 0) {
            throw IndexOutOfBoundsException()
        }
        return (c1 shl 56) or (c2 shl 48) or (c3 shl 40) or (c4 shl 32) or
            (c5 shl 24) or (c6 shl 16) or (c7 shl 8) or c8
    }
```

Basically what this code is doing is to flip the first bit in the `Long` (by doing an `xor` with `Long.MIN_VALUE`) and then simply writing those bits, one byte at a time, from highest to lowest. Flipping the first bit ensures that negative values (in binary representation) are lexicographically smaller than positive values. It's actually a relatively simple trick, but very neat. The read process is then basically just the inverse. Using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and this algorithm, the test case in the opening post passes.